Reordering of Jordan blocks leads to similar matrices?
let us say I have a matrix A inJordan normal form with the Jordan blocks $B_1, B_2, ..., B_k$
if I rearrange the Jordan blocks for example, $B_1, B_{n-1}, B_2 , B_{n-2},B_3, B_{n-3}, ...$
to get a matrix $C$. Will $A$ be similar to $C$ i.e. can you find an invertible matrix $P$ such that $A = P^{-1}CP$.
I tried answering my question myself.
Basically I thought that you could make algorithm that swaps the Jordan blocks of $C$ to get $A$. It would swap two Jordan block by a series of row swaps and then a series of column swaps. The row ops would amount to a matrix $EC$ where $E$ is invertible and the column swaps would result into a matrix $ECF$ where $F$ is inv.
But I couldn't show $E=F^{-1}$ and the procedure gets complicated when the blocks you're swapping, don't have the same dimension.

try to write also $E$ as a block matrix, and notice that for a permutation matrix $P^{-1}=P^T$
